# .htaccess falling over on trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess

## TL;DR

How can I get `.htaccess` to rewrite `http://domain.com/images` to `http://domain.com/images/` (i.e. add a trailing slash to URLs without one)? The URLs can be deeper than one level, for example `http://domain.com/images/page/1`.

## More info

Say I have a URL like this:

`http://jamwaffles2/wallpapers`

This will redirect to this in the URL bar, with the rewrite rule working fine:

`http://jamwaffles2/wallpapers/?page=wallpapers`

However

`http://jamwaffles2/wallpapers/` (note trailing slash)

Rewrites fine to

`http://jamwaffles2/index.php?page=wallpapers` (not visible to user)

With a nice `http://jamwaffles2/wallpapers/` in the address bar.

The issue here is that when a trailing slash isn't given to the URL, the URL in the address bar changes to a not-so-pretty one. Can someone offer a solution to this?

Here's my .htaccess:

```
# turn rewriting on
RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://jamwaffles2/home

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&var1=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4 [L,NC,QSA]
```

As a side note, there are more levels to the URL; the `.htaccess` should make that apparent (e.g. `http://jamwaffles2/home/page/2`).

**EDIT**

Curiously, this only happens on `/wallpapers`. If I type in `http://jamwaffles2/home` it works as expected, but won't work with `http://jamwaffles2/wallpapers`.

Comment: Do you have a file called `wallpapers.php` or similar?

Comment: I do, which is what this .htacces should open via `/index.php`. It works fine for pages in the same directory as `wallpapers.php`, e.g. `home.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try this directive: `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` -- depending on Apache config it can be the deal breaker.

2) Use this code (one of possible variants) to add trailing slash for NON-EXISTING resources ONLY:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect (301 Permanent Redirect) so URL will change in browser (e.g. `example.com/hello` => `example.com/hello/`).

---

If it still does not work (for whatever the reason may be) -- if you can edit Apache config files -- please enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check the rewrite log to see why some URL failing correct rewrite. Every server can be configured differently, so the same rule may work a bit differently in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much LazyOne. I've actually resolved this issue now - it was due to an older version of the file being cached by Apache, or something; it works fine now :-)